# Frida not able to hook shared library load in time, is logged the second time

Tags: dynamic, shared-libraries, hook, frida

I'm having some trouble hooking a library that is called during runtime in my app using Frida. For context, I am able to hook into it at a specific point using LLDB. I can listen for a variable and then patch at that point it is hit and it works. I also have other Frida patches that work up to that point.

I am using this:

`const binarybase = Process.enumerateModules().filter(ex => ex.name.includes("binaryname"))[0].base;`

The reason I am doing it this way is because the name of the lib is different each time it runs. The first time it is called I get:

{"type":"error","description":"TypeError: cannot read property 'base' of undefined","stack":"TypeError: cannot read property 'base' of undefined\n at onEnter (/filename.js:55)","fileName":"/filename.js","lineNumber":55,"columnNumber":1}

The second time it is called it finds the name.

I am calling the above inside an interceptor.attach at a specific address:

```
Interceptor.attach(addr3, {
    onEnter: function(args) {
        
        
        const binarybase = Process.enumerateModules().filter(ex => ex.name.includes("binaryname"))[0].base;
        console.log("binaryname base address = " + binarybase);

// patch binary here after console log hits

    },
});
```

Is enumerateModules with filter the quickest way to do this or is it slower than some other methods? Is there another way I could try? I am using this way because the dynamic library name is not the same each time it is called so I can't do it the usual way.

Would really appreciate some guidance or some other things I might be able to try...

Comment: Assuming that the library files do not change the changing name must be the result of code that runs after loading the library which overwrites the original library name. May be it would be easier to identify the library before this name obfuscation code is executed. Have you tried to hook `dlopen` to get the library reference as early as possible?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I did think about using dlopen thank you I will see if I can explore that route, or maybe I can hook into the method that changes the name of this lib to keep it constant each time?